# Android rotate only status bar and buttons

Tags: android, android-studio, screen-rotation

I decided to develop my own camera activity since I need to force the user to take a 1:1 ratio picture; just like Instagram. I created my activity based on this activity from an open-source project:

https://github.com/pocorall/scaloid-apidemos/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.java

Now I'm trying to handle the screen rotation to avoid the layout from being rotated. In other words, I want to keep the layout from rotating and rotate only the buttons and the status bar depending on the device rotation.

I already declared my activity to listen for config changes in the manifest file.

```
<activity
android:name=".activity.CameraActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Eyes.NoActionBar"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing|stateHidden">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop rotation of layout

- Add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` into manifest

Detect rotation for individual buttons

- Call `Display.getRotation()` to check how much the screen has roated and adjust buttons accordingly

Comment: If I add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` into the manifest, does the activity still call `onConfigurationChanged()`? And what about the status bar when the user rotate his device in landscape mode?